# How to configure multiple QnA models inside projects appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, botframework, dispatch, azure-qna-maker

I have a bot which runs on Luis & QnA model using Dispatch tool. Now the problem here is i have made another QnA model which i want to configure in my bot project i.e i want to update the Knowledge base id in the appsettings.json  of my c# project.
How can i do that? as without that my second QnA is not getting picked.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "MicrosoftAppId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "MicrosoftAppPassword": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

  "QnAKnowledgebaseId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "QnAAuthKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "QnAEndpointHostName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

   "QnAKnowledgebaseId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "QnAAuthKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "QnAEndpointHostName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",



  "LuisAppId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "LuisAPIKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "LuisAPIHostName": "xxxxxx",



 `enter code here`"AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just set it in app settings as MODELNAME_QnAKnowledgebaseId, etc and then call it using either a simple switch case or dispatch in your bot?

```
},

  "MicrosoftAppId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "MicrosoftAppPassword": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

  "MODEL1_QnAKnowledgebaseId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "MODEL1_QnAAuthKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "MODEL1_QnAEndpointHostName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

  "MODEL2_QnAKnowledgebaseId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "MODEL2_QnAAuthKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "MODEL2_QnAEndpointHostName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

  "LuisAppId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "LuisAPIKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "LuisAPIHostName": "xxxxxx",

 "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Then in your BotServices:

```
public BotServices(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            // Read the setting for cognitive services (LUIS, QnA) from the appsettings.json

            MODEL1_QnA = new QnAMaker(new QnAMakerEndpoint
            {
                KnowledgeBaseId = configuration["MODEL1_QnAKnowledgebaseId"],
                EndpointKey = configuration["MODEL1_QnAEndpointKey"],
                Host = configuration["MODEL1_QnAEndpointHostName"]
            });
        }
```

Comment: On implementing like this..my bot stops working..i have debugged and on making changes in my BotServices class..this thing happens

Comment: i am using single qna service for multiple qna knowledge bases..is this the right approach or do we have to create multiple services for each knowledge base?